# extract last number in every row of CSV file

Tags: python

This is my second day of csv file handling, my 
CSV file:

-RÎ¹alisÎ¹ par James Wan--- Vos moments prÎ¹fÎ¹rÎ¹s ! (Spoilers inside) 1
-Source Code- News et Critique ! 2
ALED - A la carte 2
ALED - Bistrot 6

I would like to extract the number at the end and store it in another file like this:

```
hindex
1
2
2
6
```

The number could even be two digit..

Comment: Do you mean "csv" as in "comma separated values"?

Comment: What's your OS?  What tools do you have on hand to attempt this?  Did you put any thought into this at all before posting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your content is in a file say `tst.csv` you can do something like

```
>>> with open("tst.csv") as fin, open("tst.out","w" )as fout:
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(line.rpartition(" ")[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

By definition the csv format is comma separated, therefore we use `split(',')`. `infp` is your input file handle (assuming the name of your data file is 'data.csv'), `outfp` for output:

```
with open('data.csv') as infp, open('data.out', 'w') as outfp:
   for line in infp:
      outfp.write(line.split(',')[-1])
```

EDIT: not withstanding the title of the question, apparently the file itself is **not** in CSV format. Therefore this solution would have to use `split(' ')`.

Answer (score 0):

This is pseudo code:

```
 foreach line
     split the line words by space and get the last index.
```